# Optimize SQL query with and or and structure in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, where-clause, sql-function

I have a function that has to convert currencies based on a conversion rate retrieved from a a table with historic values. It takes four parameters (@to_curr, @from_curr, @trans_date, @gl_cmp) adn returns the exchange rate.

The table structure is

- `currencypk int primary key`
- `gl_crcnv_bdate datetime`
- `gl_crcnv_edate datetime`
- `gl_crcnv_rate float`
- `gl_cmp_key char(30)` (we have multiple companies this identifies each one)
- `gl_CRNCY_TO char(30)`
- `gl_CRNCY_FROM char(30)`

Below is my code and when I insert this in a function it causes a MASSIVE increase in execution time. I have a pretty good idea where the bottle neck is in my function but I am stuck on how to rewrite it. The reason why I have a ugly where clause with a (and) or (and) setup is because not every relationship is reversed.

For example there are records with a conversion rate from USD to GBP but there doesn't exist one at all with GBP to USD. That fact accounts for the case statement in the `SELECT`, to get the actual conversion that doesn't exist in the table. The `isnull` is in case it returns nothing, so it uses 1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    isnull((SELECT convert(decimal(5,4),  
                   case 
                      when @to_curr <> gl_CRNCY_TO 
                         then (1/gl_crcnv_rate)
                         else gl_crcnv_rate
                    end)
            FROM 
               [TABLE]
            WHERE 
               gl_cmp_key = @gl_cmp   
               AND ((gl_CRNCY_TO = @from_curr AND gl_CRNCY_FROM = @to_curr) 
                    OR (gl_CRNCY_TO = @to_curr AND gl_CRNCY_FROM = @from_curr))
               AND @trans_date BETWEEN gl_crcnv_bdate AND gl_crcnv_edate), 1)
```

Comment: The bottleneck IS your function, not the code inside it. Scalar functions are horrible from a performance perspective. This looks like an excellent candidate for an inline table valued function which will perform better than a scalar function. Make sure you don't have multiple lines in your table function though or the performance will suffer greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT isnull(SELECT convert(decimal(5,4),  gl_crcnv_rate)
              FROM (select 1/gl_crcnv_rate as gl_crcnv_rate
                    from [TABLE]
                    WHERE gl_cmp_key = @gl_cmp AND 
                          gl_CRNCY_TO = @from_curr AND 
                          gl_CRNCY_FROM = @to_curr AND 
                          @trans_date BETWEEN gl_crcnv_bdate AND gl_crcnv_edate
                    UNION
                    select gl_crcnv_rate
                    from [TABLE]
                    WHERE gl_cmp_key = @gl_cmp AND 
                          gl_CRNCY_TO = @to_curr AND 
                          gl_CRNCY_FROM = @from_curr AND 
                          @trans_date BETWEEN gl_crcnv_bdate AND gl_crcnv_edate
                    ) sq,
              1)
```

This assumes that if both possible conversion records exists then the conversion factor will evaluate to the same value, and that there is an index that the query can use.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I can think of based on privided information

Create computed column so that we don't have to calculate it for ever query.

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE] ADD  gl_crcnv_rate_invert AS (1/gl_crcnv_rate) PERSISTED;
```

Craete index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_cmpkey_crncyto_crncyfrom_bdate_edate ON [TABLE] (gl_CRNCY_TO, gl_CRNCY_FROM, gl_crcnv_bdate, gl_crcnv_edate)
```

Comment: I don't think the calculated field will do much. Also, the index might help, but it's incomplete : you forgot `gl_cmp_key`. I'd also put end-date in there first and add begin-date after it. Since you're more likely to have a need for the latest rate available you will have less false hits that way.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Bannisters' answer already is a step forward but I'd to one further and change the code to:

```
SELECT convert(decimal(5,4),  Coalesce( -- direct lookup
                                       (SELECT TOP 1 gl_crcnv_rate 
                                          FROM [TABLE]
                                         WHERE gl_cmp_key    = @gl_cmp 
                                           AND gl_CRNCY_FROM = @from_curr 
                                           AND gl_CRNCY_TO   = @to_curr 
                                           AND @trans_date BETWEEN gl_crcnv_bdate AND gl_crcnv_edate),
                                        -- reverse lookup
                                       (SELECT TOP 1 1/gl_crcnv_rate 
                                          FROM [TABLE]
                                         WHERE gl_cmp_key    = @gl_cmp 
                                           AND gl_CRNCY_TO   = @from_curr 
                                           AND gl_CRNCY_FROM = @to_curr 
                                           AND @trans_date BETWEEN gl_crcnv_bdate AND gl_crcnv_edate),
                                        -- fallback
                                        1))
```

The `COALESE()` is smart enough to not do the second block if it finds that the first one already returned a match. It also spares you the `UNION` (which should have been an `UNION ALL` in the first place!).

Additionally, you'll also want to make sure to have an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON [TABLE] (gl_cmp_key, gl_CRNCY_FROM, gl_CRNCY_TO, gl_crcnv_edate, gl_crcnv_bdate)
```

Frankly, I'd make the current PK non-clustered and this one clustered, that way you save a lot on bookmark lookups; the only downside being that you'll probably need to rebuild/defragment the index once in a while as adding new records will cause fragmentation over time as new values get squeezed in between existing records...  (side-mark: do you even need currencypk ? if not, simply make `gl_cmp_key, gl_CRNCY_FROM, gl_CRNCY_TO, gl_crcnv_edate, gl_crcnv_bdate, currencypk' the new PK... rather ugly, but functionally just as valid and it saves quite a bit on space used).

The reason you want to have `edate` before `bdate` is that you'll likely be looking for the latest rate anyway. Assuming you have 20 rates sitting in there, they will all have a begin-date that is before today, but only a few (well, unless you can predict the future, only one) will have an end-date that is after today.

Some further advice: if you want performance, you should get away from Scalar Functions. They're notoriously slow in MSSQL =( Easy to use, but they cause massive overhead when used in set-based operations; e.g. updating a couple of 1000 records at once.

I'm assuming you now have something along the lines of :

```
UPDATE [INVOICE]
   SET target_amount = base_amount * dbo.fn_get_rate(gl_cmp, base_ccy, target_ccy, invoice_date)
 WHERE blah = blah
```

If you change it to below it will be remarkably faster, although I agree that it's a lot less easy to re-use... can't have it all I guess =)

```
UPDATE [INVOICE]
   SET target_amount =  Coalesce( -- direct lookup
                                       (SELECT TOP 1 [INVOICE].base_amount * d.gl_crcnv_rate 
                                          FROM [TABLE] d
                                         WHERE d.gl_cmp_key    = [INVOICE].gl_cmp 
                                           AND d.gl_CRNCY_FROM = [INVOICE].base_ccy
                                           AND d.gl_CRNCY_TO   = [INVOICE].target_ccy 
                                           AND [INVOICE].invoice_date BETWEEN d.gl_crcnv_bdate AND d.gl_crcnv_edate),
                                        -- reverse lookup
                                       (SELECT TOP 1 [INVOICE].base_amount * r.gl_crcnv_rate 
                                          FROM [TABLE] r
                                         WHERE r.gl_cmp_key    = [INVOICE].gl_cmp 
                                           AND r.gl_CRNCY_TO   = [INVOICE].target_ccy
                                           AND r.gl_CRNCY_FROM = [INVOICE].base_ccy
                                           AND [INVOICE].invoice_dateBETWEEN r.gl_crcnv_bdate AND r.gl_crcnv_edate),
                                        -- fallback
                                        [INVOICE].base_amount))
 WHERE blah = blah
```

Comment: You are right about not using a function and writing it inline to make it faster, it's much faster but orders from above prevent that option.  I appreciate your feedback and the coalesce trick is something I didn't know.  i already had the indexes in place, just as you said they should be and when i added them it was a huge improvement.   Thanks again!!!!!